# Cast Type T(byte?[]) to Type byte[]

Tags: c#, generics

This is the current code I have

```
returnString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])Convert.ChangeType((input_Value as byte?[]), typeof(byte[])));
```

I have tried everything possible in trying to get this T to cast to byte[]
But since the T is originally a byte?[], the casting to byte[] causes the value to become null
Preventing me from ever converting to utf8 format.

Comment: You could do `nullableBytes.Cast<byte>().ToArray()`

Comment: If your source value has type byte?[] so how do you want to cast byte? null value to byte? "false"?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guide on posting code and [edit] questions with enough code. It is very unclear what `T` you are talking about and why post marked with "generic" tag

Comment: `nullableBytes.OfType<byte>().ToArray()`, assuming you want to exclude the `null` entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast `byte?` to `byte` directly without conditions. The main thing you should determine how `null` will be converted in `byte` value. For example, `null` in `byte?` will be converted to `0`. So, you can use LINQ [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) to projects each element of a sequence into a new form:

```
byte?[] input_Value = ...;
byte[] target = input_Value.Select(b => b.GetValueOrDefault()).ToArray();
var returnString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(target);
```

[`GetValueOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault) Retrieves the value of the current Nullable object, or the default value of the underlying type. You can also use [`GetValueOrDefault(defaultValue)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault) to define specific default value.

Comment: You can make the linq simpler: `input_value.Select(b => b.GetValueOrDefault())`.

Comment: @ILMTitan thank you. I have not heard about this method before